# How can I create a distribution in Python using Min, Max, Mean and Standard Deviation?

Tags: python, numpy, simulation, distribution, montecarlo

As the title states, I am trying to create a distribution in Python to be used in Monte Carlo simulations. I have the Minimum and Maximum values, as well as the most likely value and the Standard Deviation. Is there a way to model the distribution using all of these values?

The closest method I have found so far is splitting it so that I create the distribution like so:

```
GCH = np.arange(GCHmin, GCHmax, 0.0001)
```

```
GCH = np.random.normal(GCHavg, GCHstdv, num_reps)
```

This method does work, but I feel like there must be a better way to do it, as doing the simulation this way matches the results I am trying to recreate at the 50th percentile, but at the 10th and 90th percentiles there is a bit of difference from the desired result.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mean or most likely value ?? And what do you expect from the extreme deciles ?

Comment: these parameters don't characterize a unique distribution. You can imagine both uniform and truncated normal could be fit to the same parameters, yet the resulting samples will have wildly different properties

Comment: It is the most likely value, my bad. I am using this distribution in a simulation to replicate the results of an equation, along with a few other variables. Both p10 and p90 values are out by roughly 5%. The paper I am attempting to replicate states that these values were used, so I would assume that there is a way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What you’re asking is actually a distribution modeling question rather than a programming one. This would be a better fit on CrossValidated (stats.stackexchange.com), but I would expect responses there to be similar to what @Marat said. Overall I’d suggest you pursue a distributional modeling approach rather than trying to just match four summary statistics.

Comment: @JamesBlack can you share the paper?

Comment: There are infinite distributions matching the statistics you've listed.

Comment: The paper that I am trying to replicate is (Sarhosis, V., Hosking, L.J. and Thomas, H.R., 2016. Carbon sequestration potential of the South Wales Coalfield. Environmental Geotechnics, 5(4), pp.234-246.) It does not specify a particular method used for generating the distribution, only that these 4 values have been used. In the simulation there are 4 such distributions that are simulated.